# Add tag for "tax" for tax law questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I just asked a tax law question, but there was no tax tag. Can that be added?

Answer (score 2):

I've edited the question to add the [tax-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tax-law) tag but you'll need to accept the revision.